# Google Instance using GSuite/Gmail to send mail

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, gmail, gmail-api

Having issues with sending mail from wordpress bitnami build, using GCE instance.

I know the normal SMTP ports are closed on GCE, but I used the gmail API, very similar to the following guide to create an API connection.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/

All setup seems to be fine, and the test email shows the following;

```
2017-11-01 18:19:56 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ()
2017-11-01 18:19:57 Connection: opened
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP m126sm942672wmf.31 - gsmtp"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP m126sm942672wmf.31 - gsmtp
2017-11-01 18:19:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.MYDOMAIN.com
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [35.189.77.174]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-11-01 18:19:57 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
2017-11-01 18:19:57 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH
2017-11-01 18:19:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing connection m126sm942672wmf.31 - gsmtp"
2017-11-01 18:19:57 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection m126sm942672wmf.31 - gsmtp
2017-11-01 18:19:57 Connection: closed
```

Seems to be connecting and authorising fine but it results in no email sent/received. I've tried TSL (587) and SSL (465)

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to set option to less secure http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

if you set up gsuit as well, set up both to less secure.
http://admin.google.com/